# Can't find generic USB audio driver for a Samson COU1 USB microphone

Tags: drivers, audio

I am unable to use a Samson USB CO1U microphone on a PC running XP, SP3.  When I plug it into the USB port, Windows generates the sound indicating that it has found new hardware, and the green LED on the mic lights.  But, it does not work, and the device manager reports that it cannot find a driver after searching.  The same mic works on a Vista machine.

Samson has no driver on their Web site, and insists that the generic audio driver in Windows should work.  (http://www.samsontech.com/PRODUCTS/productpage.cfm?prodID=1810).

I cannot find a generic USB audio driver at Microsoft.com.

Can anyone help?

Larry

Answer (score 2):

Are you connected to the internet and allowing Device Manager to search Windows Update? That worked for me.

As an aside, I contacted Samson support about this mic: they had a specialized driver, but it was poorly written and introduced cracks, pops, ticking noises, clipping, etc. into the recorded audio. Samson support suggested that I uninstall their driver and let windows update pick it back up -- and this worked marvelously.

Don't forget that with this mic you may need to go into recording properties and set it as your default or selected recording source, or no dice, Chicago.

Comment: When I let it search for drivers, it returns the message "the best driver for your audio device is already installed."

When I look at the volume control it shows a volume control for Firefox! Something is clearly amiss.

Could you send me the driver that is working for you? Are you running Vista?

Larry

PS -- like you, I got nowhere with Samson.

Comment: I've got it working both on Vista and XP. I wonder if there is some remnant of the Samson driver still on your system that is keeping Windows Update from accepting the older driver? Can you try a "roll back" there?